Problem with my AC
I got complete replacement of HVAC and water heater 2 months ago.
Everything worked for couple of weeks and one day I heard grinding noise when AC started, noise faded away in 20-30 seconds so I ignored it. After sometime, I realized that it was not cooling.
HVAC company came back and found that breaker was tripped. They checked compressor, did some testing and found that it could be faulty Contactor, they replaced it and AC started working again without any noise.
After few days, I heard the same noise again when AC started, I touched the plenum and found that it was not cool, I checked breaker but it was fine. I reset my thermostat to stop AC.
After 15-30 min, I adjusted my thermostat again to start AC and it started without any noise this time and started cooling down.
Can someone tell me What could be the problem with my AC?
Noise was coming from the area where the refrigerant lines go inside Evaporator coil unit, check the picture.


insufficient (low) coolant level will overeat the compressor. check the label for how much coolant is needed
